# Particle Filter for Tracking using Magnetic Data

Tags: python, particle-filter

I want to track a user using only the magnetometer data from their smartphone. For that I calculated the magnetic reading of every part of a room using an app. Then I put those readings in a python script and used `matplotlib.tri.Triangulation` to plot them on the floor map of the room. That part is accurate.

The dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
      time       Bx      By       Bz     BT         x          y
0   0.002255    0.64    0.08    -0.19   0.67    0.000000    0.000000
1   0.004133    0.24    -0.02   -0.11   0.27    0.000779    0.000779
2   0.015202    0.19    -0.17   -0.30   0.39    0.001559    0.001559
3   0.024648    0.19    -0.39   -0.47   0.64    0.002338    0.002338
4   0.034053    0.04    -0.39   -0.32   0.51    0.003118    0.003118
```

Issue is with particle filter which is not accurate enough. Here is how I did it:

1. I took a test file with only time and magnetic readings. Dataframe `df_test` Looks like this:

```
       time       Bx     By       Bz     BT
0   0.001725    -0.04   0.47    -0.58   0.75
1   0.009090    -0.02   0.64    -0.60   0.88
2   0.018993    -0.02   0.68    -0.45   0.81
3   0.030365    0.00    0.64    -0.28   0.70
4   0.039492    -0.08   0.51    -0.06   0.51
```

2. I check where `df_test['BT']` matched `df['BT']`. For all matches I noted the `x` and `y` from `df`. These are my particles.
3. For each `df_test['BT']` I check the previous one for particles closest from both `x` and `y` to current one. I discard the other particles that have no matches.
4. This process is done for all particles until all rows in `df_test` are processed.

The result is accurate on a lot of indexes. However there are huge outliers.

Is my approach correct as far as particle filtering is concerned? How can I improve my results?

Edit: I took readings at different parts of the room, then interpolated using python. It is also assumed for sake of simplicity  that data is noise-free. The phone was not turned at all but kept in the same orientation and direction for both floor map and test, whereas I moved with same speed in both cases. Repeated readings in the same spot of the room yielded similar magnetic data so yes its IMU works.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to include information about the following: your filter seems to contain the implicit assumptions that $x$ and $y$ are laid out on a grid with a spacing of .0007795 whatevers (meters?  cubits?  miles?).  Is that correct?  Your filter also seems to contain the implicit assumption that your magnetometer data is noise-free -- is that correct (the assumption, not whether it is or not).  You seem to assume that moves are never more than one grid square -- is that correct?  How rapidly does the phone move, turn, etc.?  Does its IMU work?

Comment: @TimWescott I have edited the question. Thanks